# Calculate cyclomatic complexity at run time for generated program tree

Tags: code-analysis, cyclomatic-complexity

I am running an evolutionary algorithm that automatically generates S-expressions that represent an abstract syntax tree.  From there I generate C code to create a compilable program.

For each generated expression I need to calculate the cyclomatic complexity to be used in the fitness calculation.  I have noticed that there are tools available to do so (such as the [metrics Eclipse plugin](http://eclipse-metrics.sourceforge.net/)), but I was hoping for something that could analyze a more generic program representation.

I could see calling an external tool, however I think that would significantly increase my execution time.  Is there a simple way to calculate cyclomatic complexity via some sort of formula that takes into account S-expressions or abstract syntax trees?

Answer (score 1):

If your generated programs are goto-free (e.g., "structured" programs), you can compute cyclomatic complexity by using a simple rule:

```
CC(p) =  #conditionals +1
```

This is a fact for structured programs.  You only need the full definition if your programs are a spaghetti control flow tangle.

Note that conditionals should count while and for loops (as they contain conditionals) and the expression short-circuit branching operators && and ||.